# OpenGL - circle not being drawn smooth

Tags: c, opengl

I am drawing a circle using OpenGL, with the set of calls being:

```
float delta_theta = 0.001;
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // OR GL_LINE_LOOP


glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


for (angle = 0; angle < 2*3.1415; angle += delta_theta)
   glVertex3f( radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle), 0 );

glEnd();
```

The problem is that the circle is not smooth. I am moving (translating) the circle along axes; at some points it becomes smooth, but mostly, it's like a blot, please see the attached screenshot.

Any suggestions as to what I could do to smoothen the circle?[image: Nonsmooth circle]

Comment: Avoid using geometry to draw small shapes.  Instead of lots of triangles, just use two triangles (to make a square) and then use a texture or fragment shader to draw the circle.  You can also use `GL_POINT_SMOOTH` if your circle is small enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you not try to implement this with lines or a filled polygon for one thing.

Use a single `GL_POINT` and enable `GL_POINT_SMOOTH`. That will rasterize the point as a filled circle instead of the normal square. It will be much more efficient, provided you use a point size your implementation supports for anti-aliased points (often up to ~ **63.5** on NV implementations, more on others).

Comment: thank you. after using GL_POINT, with GL_POINT_SMOOTHING, one can see the smoothing effect around the edges. I am accepting the answer, but any suggestions to make the edge sharper?

Comment: Sharper? `GL_POINT_SMOOTH` is **supposed** to generate a circle with the radius defined by your `glPointSize (...)`. Making a circle sharper does not make much sense to me. Can you point me to a diagram illustrating what you are talking about?